# R - sf and osmdata: Color streets based on which district they belong to

Tags: r, openstreetmap, r-sf

I am trying to plot the streets of a town in different colors based on which district they belong to:

```
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
theme_set(theme_classic())

bb <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city", format_out = "sf_polygon") %>%
  st_buffer(.05)

town <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

streets <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = c("residential", 
                                             "primary", 
                                             "secondary", 
                                             "tertiary", 
                                             "unclassified")) %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

boundary <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "9") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

st_split(streets$osm_lines, boundary$osm_lines %>% 
           filter(admin_level == 9) %>% 
           st_buffer(.05)) %>% 
  st_join(town$osm_multipolygons %>% 
            filter(admin_level == 9)) -> street_split

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = street_split, aes(color = name.y)) +
  geom_sf(data = boundary$osm_lines %>% 
            filter(admin_level == 9) %>% 
            st_buffer(.05))
```

[image]

However, as you can see, there are still some blue lines below the black line which indicated the border. I thought this issue should be resolved by using `st_split` which should split the lines into different parts where it intersects with the border. How can I make the plot that I want?

Answer (score 1):

You have to calculate `st_intersection(s)` between streets and `boundary$osm_multipolygons`, like:

```r
library(osmdata)
library(sf)
library(lwgeom)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)
theme_set(theme_classic())

bb <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city", format_out = "sf_polygon") %>%
  st_buffer(.05)

town <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "boundary", value = "administrative") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

streets <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "highway", value = c("residential", 
                                             "primary", 
                                             "secondary", 
                                             "tertiary", 
                                             "unclassified")) %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

boundary <- getbb("Zaprešić", featuretype = "city") %>% 
  opq() %>% 
  add_osm_feature(key = "admin_level", value = "9") %>% 
  osmdata_sf() %>% 
  trim_osmdata(bb)

boundary$osm_multipolygons |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot()

str_sjever <- streets$osm_lines |>
  st_intersection(boundary$osm_multipolygons[2,])

str_center <- streets$osm_lines |>
  st_intersection(boundary$osm_multipolygons[1,])

str_sjever |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(add = TRUE, col = "red")

str_center |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(add = TRUE, col = "blue")
```

[image]

For ggplot just `rbind` both `str_` and recodnize by `name.1`

Let's go to details. For simplicity let's take only one street (Ulica Matije Skurjenija) and your buffer used for `st_split` and plot them.

```r
b <- boundary$osm_lines |>
  dplyr::filter(admin_level == 9) |>
  st_buffer(.05)

ul <- streets$osm_lines |>
  subset(osm_id == "54607253")

ulbb <- st_bbox(ul)

boundary$osm_multipolygons |>
  sf::st_geometry() |>
  plot(axes = TRUE,
       xlim = c(ulbb[[1]]-0.0005 , ulbb[[3]]+0.0005),
       ylim = c(ulbb[[2]]-0.0005, ulbb[[4]]+0.0005))

b |>
  plot(add = TRUE, col=alpha(rgb(0.5,0.5,0.5), 0.5))

ul |>
  plot(add = TRUE, lwd = 3, col = "green")
```

[image]

The street is in and outside the buffer. `st_split` returns `geometrycolection` consisting of two `linestrings`.

```r
ul |>
  st_asewkt()
#> [1] "SRID=4326;LINESTRING(15.7949668 45.8696493,15.7954429 45.8696314,15.7955076 45.869629,15.7956869 45.8696239,15.7961363 45.8696069,15.7966731 45.8695896,15.7975181 45.8695601,15.798326 45.869525,15.7988878 45.8694998,15.7990484 45.8694926,15.7999966 45.8694673,15.8001948 45.8694543,15.8003778 45.8694469,15.8004852 45.8694425,15.8018022 45.8693889,15.8022611 45.8693423,15.8025538 45.8692837,15.8026059 45.8692681,15.8028883 45.8691835,15.8030056 45.8691484)"

st_split(ul, b) |>
  st_asewkt()
#> [1] "SRID=4326;GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(15.7949668 45.8696493,15.7954429 45.8696314,15.7955076 45.869629,15.7956869 45.8696239,15.7961363 45.8696069,15.7966731 45.8695896,15.7975181 45.8695601,15.798326 45.869525,15.7988878 45.8694998,15.7990484 45.8694926,15.7999966 45.8694673,15.8001948 45.8694543,15.8003778 45.8694469,15.8004852 45.8694425,15.8018022 45.8693889,15.8022611 45.8693423,15.8025538 45.8692837,15.8026059 45.8692681,15.8028883 45.8691835,15.8029886 45.8691535),LINESTRING(15.8029886 45.8691535,15.8030056 45.8691484))"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>